# Splitting hierarchies from datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, hierarchy

I have a datatable which contains multiple hierarchies with different heights which I need to split.

eg.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Account        | Hierarchy Account|
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          5          |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          6          |                  |
|---------------------|------------------
|          7          |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          8          |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Below is what I have tried so far.

```
private List<DataTable> SplitDataTablesOnHierarchy(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            List<DataTable> dataTablesList = new List<DataTable>();
            List<string> listTemp = new List<string>();

            var HierarchyAccounts = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.Field<string>("Hierarchy Account Number") == "");

            foreach(var topAccount in TopAccounts )
            {
                //Check if account exists in Hierarchy Account Number
                var topAccountExists = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Any(m => m.Field<string>("Hierarchy Account Number") == topAccount.Field<string>("Account Number"));
                if (topAccountExists == true)
                {
                    DataTable newDataTable = dataTable.Clone();
                    newDataTable.ImportRow(payerAccount);
                    dataTablesList.Add(newDataTable);
                }
                //Top Accounts found and added to tempList
            }
            //CreateDataTable with Top Accounts
            foreach(DataTable dTable in dataTablesList)
            {
                bool bottomHierarchyReached = true;
                var TempSearch = dTable.Rows;

                while(bottomHierarchyReached)
                {
                    foreach(DataRow account in TempSearch)
                    {
                        var rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.Field<string>("Hierarchy Account Number") == account.Field<string>("Account Number")).CopyToDataTable();
                        if(rows.Rows.Count == 0)
                        {
                            bottomHierarchyReached = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TempSearch = rows.Rows;
                            dTable.Rows.Add(rows.Rows);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return dataTablesList;
        }
```

My thought process above was to first find the highest accounts in the hierarchy, create new datatables with those accounts and then drill down and add the following levels to the relevant datatable recursively since I do not know the height of each hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by creating a tempList which keeps the all of the lower levels while searching through the level above.
Once the loop through the SearchList is done we assign the tempList to it.
And then search through the next level of the hierarchy.

```
       foreach (DataTable dTable in dataTablesList)
        {
            bool bottomHierarchyReached = true;
            var SearchList = dTable.AsEnumerable().Select(p=> new { HierarchyAccount = p.Field<string>("Hierarchy Account Number"),
                Account = p.Field<string>("Account Number")
            }).ToList();

            var tempList = SearchList.ToList();
            tempList.Clear();

            while (bottomHierarchyReached)
            {
                tempList.Clear();
                foreach (var account in SearchList)
                {
                    var rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.Field<string>("Hierarchy Account Number") == account.Account);
                    if(rows.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        bottomHierarchyReached = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempList.AddRange(rows.AsEnumerable().Select(p => new {
                            HierarchyAccount = p.Field<string>("Hierarchy Account Number"),
                            Account = p.Field<string>("Account Number")
                        }).ToList());

                        foreach(var row in rows)
                        {
                            dTable.ImportRow(row);
                        }
                    }
                }
                SearchList = tempList.ToList();
            }
        }
```